# Reverse the file

Tags: code-challenge, file-system

I remember this was exam question long long long time ago.

There is a file say MyFile.txt, it can be any size and contains aphanumeric only

your task is to revese the words
example : **"Go beyond the traditional laptop with Surface Laptop. It's backed by the best of Microsoft, including Windows and Office"**

It should be **"Office and Windows including Microsoft, of best the by backed It's Laptop. Surface with laptop traditional the beyond Go"**

The size of the text in the file is unknown.

Comment: This is a file, the file size is unknown, you cant find the length of the string in the file.

Comment: I think you mean alphanumeric and spaces?

Comment: This is tagged code challenge but no winning criteria is given

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Python 3, <s>77</s> <s>71</s> <s>47</s> 43 bytes

```
print(" ".join(open("f").read().split()[::-1]))
```

EDIT: Saved 6 bytes thanks to NoOneIsHere.
EDIT: Saved another 24 thanks to Jonathan Allan.

Comment: Why do you need `f = f.read()` if you only use `f` once? Why not `with open("MyFile.txt") as f:fprint(" ".join(f.read().split(" ")[::-1]))`

Comment: @NoOneIsHere I tried that before and it didn't work, probably just a typo. Thanks!

Comment: You can remove the `" "` from the `split()` call as it defaults to splitting on spaces.

Comment: `print(" ".join(open("MyFile.txt").read().split()[::-1]))` saves 12 bytes. Also the question only gives "Myfile.txt" as an example, you could assume the name is just "f" and save another 9.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere I don't think Reversal exists on PPCG.

Comment: @LyricLy https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/reversal